# Can't change max_input_vars in PHP

Tags: php, apache2, moodle, virtualmin

I need to raise the max_input_vars value in php for a moodle installation.
However when I change the value in my php.ini file the moodle web installer still prompts:

`PHP setting max_input_vars must be at least 5000.`

phpinfo() shows:

`max_input_vars => 5000 => 5000`

also editing the .htaccess file had no effect.

Comment: Are you sure the php.ini file you changed is being used? `phpinfo` should show which php.ini is loaded. Does your webhost have instructions?

Comment: Is this on your local host? Or a web host?

Comment: @JacobMulquin Yeah, the `phpinfo` shows the correct file and file path.
The thing is everything seems to be set correctly as far as the php.ini is concerned. maybe something in the moodle configuration I'm missing?

Comment: @RussellEngland localhost.

Comment: @Ludawi Maybe try setting max_input_vars to 5001?

Comment: @JacobMulquin I also tried that fix already. Sadly had no effect. I also tried a different PHP version and of courser restarted all the services.

Comment: Does there happen to be a `.htaccess` file with the Moodle install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary php file in the Moodle directory with the following and run it via the browser (running php via the command line uses a different php ini file not the apache file)

```
<?php

phpinfo();
```

This will confirm which php ini file is being used, eg `/etc/php/xx/apache2/php.ini`

Also search the page for `max_input_vars` to see what the value is.

Master is the value in `php.ini` - if its not 5000 then the wrong php ini file has been edited, or you need to restart apache

Local is the value being used - if its different to the master value, then its been overwritten by apache

In which case, check .htaccess and the conf files in the apache directories eg `etc/apache2/`

If the local value is correct - 5000 - then its been changed by code in the Moodle directory somewhere. Maybe check `config.php` or search the code for `max_input_vars`

Comment: A new upcoming version of Webmin 2.010 will allow changing Virtualmin users `max_input_vars` from `Services ⇾ PHP FPM Configuration: Resource Limits` page.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the wrong php.ini file I edited. The comment from @JacobMulquin directly to the question and the answer from @RusselEngland helped me find that out.

I have a webserver (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) running with multiple PHP versions as fpm, and therefore I had to edit the /etc/php/8.3/***fpm***/php.ini instead of the /etc/php/8.3/***apache2***/php.ini.

I thought this should be posted as an answer so others struggling with the same problem may find it faster.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in Moodle installer on Fedora. After changing `/etc/php.ini` with

```
max_input_vars = 5000
```

error would not go away even after `max_input_vars` changed. Appears it is not enough to restart web server (apache in my case)

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

also needed to

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```